# Display multiple Blob files from mySQL

Tags: mysql, jsp, blob, gallery

I want to create a gallery in a java web app project. The gallery reads images that are stored as BLOB files in a mySQL DB. This is what I have done but only the first Image in the db displays. Is it possible to read multiple BLOB images from a db or would I be better off creating a gallery from images stored in a folder?

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>

<%
Blob image = null;
Connection con = null;
byte[ ] imgData = null ;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/capture","root","");
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select file from photoentry");
if (rs.next()) {
image = rs.getBlob(1);
imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());
}
else {
out.println("Display Blob Example");
out.println("image not found for given id>");
return;
}
// display the image
response.setContentType("image/jpg");
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
o.write(imgData);
o.flush();
o.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
out.println("Unable To Display image");
out.println("Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage());
return;
} finally {
try {
rs.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
%>
```

Comment: It's possible, AND you'd probably be better off creating a gallery from images stored in a folder.

Comment: where you are displaying image ,post that code also .